# Using Register-WmiEvent to notify when a script starts executing

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

I'm totally new to PS and I've been trying to come up with a way to detected when a script, say Foo.(ps1 | pl | py | bar) begins execution so that I may run a powershell script upon that event. I've started with using the following example from [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/08/30/exploring-wmi-with-powershell-v2.aspx) and I've added an if statement to filter everything except PS executions.

```
$Query = 'SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace'            
$action = {            
    $e = $Event.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent 
    if($e.ProcessName -eq "powershell.exe") {           
        $fmt = 'ProcessStarted: (ID={0,5}, Parent={1,5}, Time={2,20}, Name="{3}")'            
        $msg = $fmt -f $e.ProcessId, $e.ParentProcessId, $event.TimeGenerated, $e.ProcessName            
        Write-host -ForegroundColor Red $msg            
    }
}            
Register-WmiEvent -Query $Query -SourceIdentifier ProcessStart -Action $Action
```

The code now detects when powershell instance is started, but I haven't found a way to access and filter the arguments passed to the instance. I would like to ensure that I only take action for the Foo script not any other PS script. Is there a way to access the arguments for the started powershell process?

Comment: Does Register-WmiEvent create a persistent WMI object or does it only exist as long as the console exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a try, you can try to match your script against the CommandLine property of the new process:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance isa 'Win32_Process'" -SourceIdentifier NewPSProcess -Action {
    $e = $EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance
    if($e.Name -eq 'powershell.exe')
    {
        #if($e.CommandLine -match 'yourScript') { ... }
        Write-host $e.CommandLine
    }
}

sleep 5
powershell -file c:\test.ps1
```

**UPDATE**
Here's an update code that captures only powershell.exe process creation (on the query level) and writes the commandLine value to a text file. I was able to view all powershell process creations (made from cmd) written to the file.

```
$query = 'Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 2 Where TargetInstance Isa "Win32_Process" And TargetInstance.Name = "powershell.exe"'
Register-WMIEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier NewPSProcess -Action {
   $EventArgs.NewEvent.TargetInstance.CommandLine | Out-File D:\scripts\temp\psevent.txt -Append
}
```

Comment: +1 for awesome start. But for some reason this seems to work sometimes, but not always. I've tried a few different ways of invoking the ps script but still it doesn't work every time. Trying to figure out if I'm missing something here :/

Comment: Using the "Windows Management Instrumentation Tester" it seems like there isn't always an created process each time PS is invoked, even from cmd.exe.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. I opened a new powershell console and registered a wmi event, then opened cmd.exe and ran these two commands one after the other: powershell  -command "&{d:\Scripts\hello.ps1}", and "powershell  -file d:\Scripts\hello.ps1". Both commands were captured and written in the powershell console.

Comment: After rebooting, I also started a new ps console and ran your (modified) example. I then ran cmd prompt and ran some ps scripts and still only some got logged! I just can't figure out why it works sometimes and other times doesn't.